# Security Certificates disappearing from trust store

Tags: macos, keychain, ssl

Publicly signed fully valid .CRT file, signed by root CA and not expired, disappears from the System Keychain. Seems to affect all sorts of Mac computers in my environment including new and fully patched machines. Users do not have admin rights so I'm fairly certain they are not the cause. Are there end user tasks a non-admin could inadvertently do to cause the cert to drop?

Comment: Hi! It seems like you've made multiple separate accounts on this site. To be able to reply to comments here and freely edit your own posts, you need to use the same account you used to ask the question. You can request an account merge from the [contact](https://apple.stackexchange.com/contact) page.

Comment: OK, can you be more specific what kind of certificate it was that diapered.

Comment: are you running Java KeyStore